# python assign built in keyword to variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing tests via assertions. Sometimes I need to negation assertion somehow.

for example:

```
def my_invalid_test(my_built_in_keyword_var):  # Invalid syntax
    assert my_built_in_keyword_var (1)

my_invalid_test(neg=(not not))  # Should pass a test
my_invalid_test(neg=not)  # Should NOT pass a test
```

I can do it (an negation) via ternary operator but it takes more (almost X2) lines of code:

```
def already_valid_test(neg):
    test_1 = some_looooooooooooooooong_statement()
    assert test_1 if not neg else not test_1  # 

already_valid_test(neg=False)  # Should pass a test
already_valid_test(neg=True)  # Should NOT pass a test
```

I tried to apply `^` (XOR), but to make it a correct result of the function always should be a bool otherwise it will just subtract (from a number for example)

So is there a way to assign a built-in keyword to a variable or implement a negation by a similar approach?

Comment: `assert bool(some_loooooooooooooooooooooooong_statement()) == not neg`?

Comment: @Samwise Thanks! You can post this comment as answer, I will accept it. It's also working with `bool(some_loooooooooooooooooooooooong_statement()) ^ neg`

Comment: You're getting a bunch of downvotes so I want to provide some constructive criticism: Please read about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). You have a good question X, but it's obscured by introducing it in terms of Y, as well as a lot of grammatical mistakes (e.g. "to negation assertion"). As well, [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) and [keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html) are two different things.

Comment: Here is nothing to do (about mistakes), the only way to avoid them - learn English rather than computer science. English isn't my native lang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler way to formulate this:

```
def already_valid_test(neg: bool) -> None:
    test_1 = some_looooooooooooooooong_statement()
    assert test_1 if not neg else not test_1  #
```

is:

```
def already_valid_test(neg: bool) -> None:
    assert neg == not some_looooooooooooooooong_statement()
```

If you wanted to do it by passing in a function, you could build one with a `lambda` expression, e.g.:

```
def my_invalid_test(my_built_in_keyword_var: Callable[[int], bool]) -> None:
    assert my_built_in_keyword_var(1)

my_invalid_test(neg=lambda x: bool(x))  # Should pass a test
my_invalid_test(neg=lambda x: not x)    # Should NOT pass a test
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort of (but not actually) assign a keyword to a variable by using the [operator module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html). The [operator.not_](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.not_) function does the same thing as the `not` operator, but as it's a function, you will be assigning the function to the variable, not the keyword. (Be aware that `not_` here has a trailing underscore, as plain `not` would be a syntax error.)

```
import operator

def already_valid_test(neg):
    assert not neg(some_looooooooooooooooong_statement())

already_valid_test(neg=operator.not_) # Should pass
already_valid_test(neg=bool)          # Should not pass
```

Note that this also uses the [bool](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool) built-in function to emulate `not not`.

Having said this, if I was writing the test I would probably use the same code as Samwise, as you don't have to import an extra module.

```
def already_valid_test(neg):
    assert bool(some_looooooooooooooooong_statement()) is not neg

already_valid_test(neg=False) # Should pass
already_valid_test(neg=True)  # Should not pass
```

(I prefer Samwise's original formulation with `bool`, as I think it makes it clearer what you are testing, but that's a matter of preference.)